# I want to selector class in <tr> inside class in <table>

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery("table[class*='BALLOON']  tr[class*='LINE_']").mouseover(function(e){




});



<table class="RESULT_CONTENT BALLOON">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> No<th>
                    <th class="showTooltipH"> Name    <th>
                    <th class="showTooltipH"> Last name<th>
                    <th clasenter code heres="showTooltipH"> Province<th>
                    <th class="showTooltipH"> Address <th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>enter code here
                <tr class="LINE_EVENT">
                    <td> 1<td>
                    <td class="showTooltip"> John<td>
                    <td class="showTooltip"> Mawin<td>
                    <td class="showTooltip"> Puket<td>
                    <td class="showTooltip"> 123 xxx xxx <td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

but it's not working.
Help me please

Comment: no `</td>` `</th>`end tags?? And your code is working. http://jsfiddle.net/G2AAv/

Comment: Be more precise. What do you mean, is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Make it easier: `$('table.BALLOON').find("tr[class^='LINE_']")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

**JsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/7yfcn/

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function() {

    $('table.BALLOON').find("tr[class*='LINE_']").mouseover(function(e){
        //put your code here...
    });
});
```

**HTML:** no change

Comment: He should change the HTML to close the tags correctly

Answer (score 0):

You're javascript should work fine. Remember to close your `<th>` and `<td>` tags, see here : http://jsfiddle.net/Ae9jq/

```
<table class="RESULT_CONTENT BALLOON">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> No</th>
        <th class="showTooltipH"> Name    </th>
        <th class="showTooltipH"> Last name</th>
        <th class="showTooltipH"> Province</th>
        <th class="showTooltipH"> Address </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="LINE_EVENT">
        <td> 1</td>
        <td class="showTooltip"> John</td>
        <td class="showTooltip"> Mawin</td>
        <td class="showTooltip"> Puket</td>
        <td class="showTooltip"> 123 xxx xxx </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You JS code is running before the table is fully loaded. Just replace the code with this, and you will be fine:

```
$(function() {jQuery("table[class*='BALLOON']  tr[class*='LINE_']").mouseover(function(e){
})});
```